# Disable networking for specific users

Tags: networking

I'm working on Ubuntu/Mint distro meant to be ran Live.  There are multiple accounts that fall into three general groups: Admin, Internet and Security.

- **Admin** is obviously has the authority to do whatever.
- **Internet** account is for using the Internet.

The other accounts are **Security** accounts.  Under no circumstances is any networking Internet, printer, Bluetooth, WiFi devices, etc, allowed.

What I'd like to do is remove the network drivers from the kernel, but that would disable the accounts that need Internet.

What are the lowest level way(s) to disable Internet for these security accounts?  I'm looking for *impossible to connect* solutions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do that with `iptables` (`ip6tables`).

##### Until reboot

On a terminal add the rule to `iptables`

```bsh
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner username -j DROP
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner username -j DROP
```

where *username* is the user that you want to disable the Internet connection. Save the file and exit.

This will add a rule to `iptables` (`ip6tables`) saying that any outgoing packages created by the specified user will be automatically dropped by it.

If you want to do the same for a complete group I suggest that instead of `--uid username` you use `--gid-owner groupname`, that will have the same effect for a complete user group.

So, for example, to prevent the group `security` from accessing the Internet the command would look something like this

```bsh
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --gid-owner security -j DROP
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --gid-owner security -j DROP
```

##### Permanent

To make the rule permanent you can create a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`, add the necessary lines to it and make it executable.

As an option use `iptables-save` (`ip6tables-save`) to save your current rules and restore them on boot.

Save the current `iptables` rules

```bsh
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables_rules
sudo ip6tables-save > /etc/ip6tables_rules
```

Open `/etc/rc.local` with your favorite text editor and at the end of the file add

```
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables_rules
/sbin/ip6tables-restore < /etc/ip6tables_rules
```

That will restore the saved rules on each boot. Be careful in noticing that *users for which you blocked only ipv4 connections will still be able to connect to the internet.*

For more informations and several more `iptables` options consult its [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/iptables).

Comment: Thanks.  That worked for Internet, but this user can still use bluetooth.  I'm testing for wireless but have not confirmed.  I seem to have the account stuck on DENY.  I tried `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner internet -j ACCEPT` but that didn't turn it back on for testing.

Comment: Ok, iptables seem to be a filter for something lower that actually makes the network connection.  What is the application making the connection possible?  Can I disable it?  If so, disabling based who is in control of the console.  This live distro is meant for multiple users, but not meant for more than one console.  So, if I can track who is using the console, I'm thinking I may be able to disable this network app based upon that users permissions.

Comment: Well, that would be your network manager in Ubuntu that would be `network-manager`, if you remove a user from the group `network` and disable the connection in `network-manager` or other similar tool he will not be able to get it up again, in the other hand user that is part of the network group will. This is another level of thinking since it disables the connection it self.

Comment: After a bit of Googling, I've found you can remove network-manager and set things up Ubuntu traditionally by editing */etc/network/interfaces*.  This doesn't seem to be the network app I'm looking to disable.  I'm looking a bit lower.  How low can we go before we get to the driver?

Comment: I was able to remove and purge network-manager.  At that point networking was disabled.  But, I was able to bring things back with this: `sudo /etc/init.d/networking` after editing `/etc/network/interfaces`  So is `/etc/init.d/networking` as low as you go?

Comment: I believe so. After that comes driver modules I think.

Comment: Multiple users can be logged to a system at the same time. Normally if any user creates a network connection everyone will be able to use it. So I think Bruno's iptables suggestion is going to be a lot more effective than controlling access to network-manager.

Answer (score 2):

Bruno's solution is good: I think probably the best self-contained solution.

Another option you can think about is to set up a firewall/proxy on a separate machine, as the gateway to the internet, which only allows connections out that provide per-user authentication.  You could use use both together for extra protection.

Answer (score 0):

If [**firewalld**](https://firewalld.org/) is part of your setup, you can block network access for a specific user using a direct rule, es:

```xml
/etc/firewalld/direct.xml
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<direct>
  <chain ipv="ipv4" 
         table="filter" 
         chain="restrict_user_ipv4"/>
  <rule ipv="ipv4" 
        table="filter" 
        chain="OUTPUT" 
        priority="1">-m owner --uid-owner user -j restrict_user_ipv4</rule>
  <rule ipv="ipv4" 
        table="filter" 
        chain="restrict_user_ipv4" 
        priority="3">-j DROP</rule>
  <chain ipv="ipv6" 
         table="filter" 
         chain="restrict_user_ipv6"/>
  <rule ipv="ipv6" 
        table="filter" 
        chain="OUTPUT" 
        priority="1">-m owner --uid-owner user -j restrict_user_ipv6</rule>
  <rule ipv="ipv6" 
        table="filter" 
        chain="restrict_user_ipv6" 
        priority="3">-j DROP</rule>
</direct>
```

Don't forget to reload with

```
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

#### References

- [Block Outgoing Network Access For a Single User Using Firewalld - Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3414921)