# How can I disable wlan for a specific user account

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I would like to disable wlan for some users while keeping it enabled for other users. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
It is important that the user accounts for which wlan is disabled should come up that way. It is not important whether the other accounts come up enabled or require to run something from the command line in order to enable wlan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable networking for specific users](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102005/disable-networking-for-specific-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly a duplicate of: [Disable Networking for Specific Users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102005/disable-networking-for-specific-users).

This method will disable and drop the networking feature for a specified user within Ubuntu. Be sure this is something that you want to do to your user before running the commands.

Comment: Yep. Adding `-o wlan0` (or whatever the wireless interface name is) after `-p all` should do the trick.

Comment: If I do this, will the user be able to override using the network manager or will he need sudo rights?

Comment: @levengli they will need sudo rights.